# PostgreSQL: filter rows by regex

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I want to verify if the string began with name(followed by 3 digits) and ends with state.

My code did this

Actual Output: NOT, NOT, YES, YES, YES, YES, NOT.

Expected Output: NOT, NOT, NOT, NOT, NOT, YES, NOT

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
("f1" varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
("f1")
VALUES
  ('name123/state/LA'),
  ('name123/state/LA/X1'),
  ('name1/state/'),
  ('nameabcccc/state/'),
  ('name3444/state/'),
  ('name444/state/'),
  ('name1/state/LA')
 ;

  SELECT f1,
  CASE when trim(f1) ~ '^name[^/]*/state\/$' then 'YES' ELSE 'NOT' END col2
  FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match your code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes its giving bad results. look at the actual results and the expected ones

Comment: You are speaking of "tmp" and "x1", but your pattern has "name" and no "x1".

Comment: @Jappa What if value is like `name344sdfdfd/state/`?

Answer (score 3):

> starts with name (followed by 3 digits) and ends with state.

That's not what your regex does. You are missing a pattern for 3 digits and the `/` character doesn't need to be escaped.

The following will do what you exepct

```
trim(f1) ~ '^name[0-9]{3}[^0-9]*/state/$'
```

So the regex makes sure

- the string starts with `^name`
- is followed by three digits `[0-9]{3}`
- is followed by any other character except a digit `[^0-9]*`
- ends with "/state/" by using `/state/$`